# How to prove this theorem for exponential equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Prove that if $a^x=a^y      a∈R$ then $x=y$ as in the exponential equation $2^x=2^3$

How can I prove this theorem, if you know what I mean

Comment: This is not always true, for example if $a=1$.

Comment: What if 1^x=1^4? it's true

Comment: $x=4$ is not true if $x=5$.

Comment: It's also not necessarily true in the complex numbers. For example:

$$e^{i\pi} = e^{i 3\pi} = ... = e^{i(2k+1)\pi} = -1$$

whenever $k$ is an integer. The key point in this discussion is you need to specify *very, very, very* clearly the framework, restrictions, and assumptions in which you are working.

Comment: a∈R, I mean only for real numbers

Answer (score 1):

$a^x = a^y$
x.log a = y.log a

log a = 0 iff a = 1.
Draw your own conclusions.